# WPF Style BasedOn Loses Setters?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I'm creating a style in the code-behind that is "BasedOn" a global resource style of the same TargetType. The new style has all of the same properties as the original, plus one additional Setter that is unique to it. It seems like the Setters are not copied over to my new style though, forcing me to loop through all of the original Setters and add them as new Setters on my style. Is there a better way to accomplish this behavior?

```
Style defaultStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("NumericFieldStyle") as Style;
Style decimalStyle = new Style(typeof(XamMaskedEditor), defaultStyle);
    // No setters in decimalStyle? There were 6 in defaultStyle
    foreach (SetterBase setter in defaultStyle.Setters)
            decimalStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
```

Comment: If you don't add the setters in the loop, do they apply in the UI, or not? I might guess that the inheritance works by linking to the BasedOn style, rather than by creating a clone of it. I'd research that.

Comment: Ah... I feel very foolish. Yes it does apply in the UI although it isn't obvious when debugging. This should help in my coding adventures. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Style` inheritance doesn't work the way you guessed. When you set the `BasedOn` property of a `Style`, it doesn't become a clone of the parent style. Instead, the parent style is applied (recursively if need be), and then the child style is applied.

If you comment out your setter loop and look at your `defaultStyle` in the debugger, you'll see only the setter you added explicitly, but `defaultStyle.BasedOn` will expand to `NumericFieldStyle` -- and there you'll see the missing setters. They'll be applied.

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) "the new style will inherit the values of the original style that are not explicitly redefined in the new style", but as you can see that's a somewhat glib way to describe what really happens in practice.